# Check validity of Apple Wallet Pass cert programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, passbook

In our app (Obj-C), we allow users to add a rewards card to Apple Wallet via a button.  We already do a check so that we only show that button if the user is on a device that has Passbook/Wallet.

Due to recent events, I'd like to build in some more safety measures around that button.

Specifically, is it possible to check whether or not the pass we'd like to add is signed by an expired cert? If so, I'd like to hide the "Add to Passbook" button from the user.

Yes, I know we should be careful about renewing our certs, but sometimes Bad Things happen and I'd rather the user experience be clean even if human error affects our cert temporarily.

We only get the pass type ID and the pass serial number from a webservice, and that is not currently changeable.

Thanks for the help!

tl;dr: in case someone screws up and forgets to renew our cert, can I check programmatically to see if our cert is good/the pass can be added, so we only show an "Add to Passbook" button if things are all ok?

Comment: If the pass has been compiled and signed before the cert expires, it will still ingest into Wallet.  Otherwise, you should handle the validation check server side, before you present the button.

Comment: Right. But if it hasn't, I don't want the user to see the "Add to Passbook" button.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should also now be using the add to wallet button, not add to passbook.